# Find the maximum $\%$ of students who could have problems in all $4$ subjects

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In a school $90\%$ of students faced problem in $maths$,
>   $80\%$ of students faced problem in $computers$,
>   $75\%$ of students faced problem in $sciences$,
>   $70\%$ of students faced problem in $social \ sciences$.
>
> Find the maximum $\%$ of students who could have 
>   problems in all $4$ subjects.

I have no idea to draw a venn diagram for $4$ sets if that s possible.

I also think that this question cannot be solved due to lack of information but not sure.

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Is every student enrolled in every course?

Comment: Yes I think so by the context and lack of data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need a Venn diagram? Can't you just say that e.g. if there are 100 pupils:
1-90 have problems in maths,
1-80 in computers,
1-75 in science,
1-70 in social science => 70% have problems in all 4?

Comment: I think you mean $\le 70$% :-).

Comment: Are you using logic that, $70\%$ of students faced problem in social sciences=.$70\%$ have problems in all $4$.?

Comment: @Frentos, sorry, => was meant as an arrow, not a maths symbol
@R K yes, if we're after a max.